# This script wont work. What i want it to do is play the remote if im holding down R

Tags: lua, roblox

This script wont work. What i want it to do is play the remote if im holding down R

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
 local mouse = player:GetMouse()
mouse.KeyDown:connect(function(key)
  if key == "r" then 
  _G.auto = true
while _G.auto == true do
game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.Backpack.Straw.LocalScript.Minus:FireServer()
wait()
end)
end
end
```

Comment: "wont work" is not a good description of what is wrong. What is it doing? does it throw errors? is it doing something completely different than expected? is it close to what you expected but not close enough to be called "working"?

Comment: It does nothing at all

Comment: Odd, it has a syntax error one would think you would get an error. are you sure it is being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to be a misplaced `)`

The problem is easier to see when your code is properly indented

```lua
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
mouse.KeyDown:connect(function(key)
    if key == "r" then
      _G.auto = true
      while _G.auto == true do
        game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.Backpack.Straw.LocalScript.Minus:FireServer()
        wait()
      end) -- This is not where the `)` should be.
    end
  end -- This is where the `)` should be.
```

Your code should produce an error on load something like:

> lua:9: unexpected symbol near ')'

This tells you that there is an unexpected `)` and what line the error is on. I am unfamiliar with the Roblox interface but I would expect it has a console where that error is being output.